# CPU giving consistent Output on executing python script in multithreading environment

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine. In that I am running a python script without using the locks. It is always giving the same output. I am not able to get why thread switching is not taking place so that Race Condition occurs.

```
from threading import *

lock = Lock()
count = 0

def task():
    global count
    for i in range(1000000):
        count += 1;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=task)
    t2 = Thread(target=task)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    print(count)
```

The given code always gives consistent output 2000000.

Output for the

```
dmidecode -t processor|grep Count -
```

```
Core Count: 4
Thread Count: 8
```

Output for the

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control
```

```
on
```

I am using the terminal to execute the python script.

```
python3 file.py
```

**Edit**

```
def check_single_threaded():
    active_threads = active_count()
    return active_threads == 1
```

This function gives output as true. I further researched and found that there is Global Interpreter Lock which allows only one thread.
Can you suggest something to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your function is getting optimized away.  Putting some indirection in there seems to produce the desired undesirable results.

```py
from threading import *
import time

lock = Lock()
count = 0

do_add = lambda x: x+1

def task():
    global count
    for i in range(1000000):
        count = do_add(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=task)
    t2 = Thread(target=task)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    print(count)
```

```bash
$ python test-thread.py 
1429397
$ python test-thread.py 
1501005
$ python test-thread.py 
1424441
```

Comment: Can you please explain with respect to Global Interpreter Lock? As only one thread per process is allowed.

Comment: Yes, @KevinMartin, just because the GIL is there doesn't mean the unit of work is as you desire.  imagine that thread `t1` is about to  to run `do_add(4)`,  and the thread `t2`just did `do_add(50000)`.  well count will be 5 after that, overwriting the `t2` count